Getting exception "detached entity passed to persist"
I am trying to delete a old child entities, create new child entities, update grandparent entity using Entity Manager using a single transaction. Below are my code:
Entity Classes
@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "GrandParent", schema = "testDbo")
public class GrandParent implements Serializable {
    @Serial
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    @Column(name = "LADDER_SEQUENCE_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    protected UUID ladderSequenceId;

    @Column(name = "LADDER_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    protected String ladderId;
    @Column(name = "LADDER_NAME")
    protected String ladderName;
    @Column(name = "LADDER_ACCOUNT_NBR")
    protected String ladderAccountNumber;
    @Column(name = "UPDATE_TS")
    protected LocalDateTime updateDate;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "ladder")
    private List<Parent> ladderRungs;
}

@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "Parent", schema = "testDbo")
public class Parent implements Serializable{
    @Serial
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    @Column(name = "LADDER_RUNG_SEQUENCE_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    private UUID ladderRungSequenceId;
    @Column(name = "LADDER_ID")
    protected String ladderId;
    @Column(name = "LADDER_RUNG_NBR")
    protected Integer ladderRungNumber;

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = CascadeType.ALL)
    @JoinColumn(name = "LADDER_SEQUENCE_ID", nullable = false)
    GrandParent ladder;

    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.EAGER, cascade = CascadeType.ALL, mappedBy = "rung")
    protected List<Child> rungPositions;
}

@Data
@Entity
@NoArgsConstructor
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table(name = "Child" , schema = "testDbo")
public class Child implements Serializable{
    @Serial
    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.UUID)
    @Column(name = "LADDER_POSITION_ID", unique = true, nullable = false)
    protected UUID ladderPositionId;

    @Column(name = "LADDER_RUNG_NBR")
    protected Integer ladderRungNumber;
    @Column(name = "POSITION_QTY")
    protected BigDecimal positionQuantity;
    
    @Override
    public Child clone()throws CloneNotSupportedException{
        return (Child) super.clone();
    }

    @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinColumn(name="LADDER_RUNG_SEQUENCE_ID", referencedColumnName = "LADDER_RUNG_SEQUENCE_ID")
    protected Parent rung;
}

DBService code:
@SuppressWarnings("all")
@Slf4j
@Service
public class EntityManagerDBService {
    @Autowired
    private EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory;

    EntityManager em;
    @Transactional
    public void ladderDBStartTransaction(){
        em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
        em.getTransaction().begin();
    }

    @Transactional
    public GrandParent getLadderByAccountNumberAndLadderId(String accountNumber, String ladderId){
        Query query = em.createNativeQuery("select * from FIXED_INCOME_LADDER_DBO.FIXED_INCOME_LADDER ld where ld.LADDER_ACCOUNT_NBR = :accountNum and ld.ladder_id = :ladderId", GrandParent.class);
        query.setParameter("accountNum", accountNumber);
        query.setParameter("ladderId", ladderId);

        if(!query.getResultList().isEmpty()){
            return (GrandParent)query.getSingleResult();
        }
        return null;
    }

    @Transactional
    public void deleteChild(List<Child> childList){
        for(Child child : childList){
            if(!em.contains(child)){
                em.merge(child);
            }
            em.remove(child);
        }
    }

    @Transactional
    public void saveGrandParent(GrandParent grandParent){
        try{
            for(Parent parent : grandParent.getLadderRungs()){
                for(Child child : parent.getRungPositions()){
                    if(!em.contains(child)){
                        //None Worked
                        em.merge(child);
                        //em.persist(child);
                    }
                }
            }
            grandParent.setUpdateDate(LocalDateTime.now());//Updating Grandparent
            em.merge(grandParent); //Want to save updated Grandparent
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        }catch (Exception ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
            em.getTransaction().rollback();
        }finally {
            em.close();
        }
    }
}

Application Code:
@SuppressWarnings("all")
@Slf4j
@Service
public class EntityManagerService {
    @Autowired
    EntityManagerDBService entityManagerDBService;

    public void process(LadderTestRequest ladderTestRequest){
        entityManagerDBService.ladderDBStartTransaction();
        GrandParent grandParent = entityManagerDBService.getLadderByAccountNumberAndLadderId(ladderTestRequest.getAccountNumber(), ladderTestRequest.getLadderId());
        log.info("GrandParent : {}", grandParent);

        try{
            List<Child> childList = new ArrayList<>();
            for(Child child : grandParent.getLadderRungs().get(3).getRungPositions()){
                Child childToSave = child.clone();
                childToSave.setRung(grandParent.getLadderRungs().get(3));
                childToSave.setPositionQuantity(new BigDecimal("10"));
                childList.add(childToSave);
            }
            entityManagerDBService.deleteChild(grandParent.getLadderRungs().get(3).getRungPositions());
            grandParent.getLadderRungs().get(3).getRungPositions().addAll(childList);
            entityManagerDBService.saveGrandParent(grandParent);
        }catch (CloneNotSupportedException ex){
            ex.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

Log and Exception
2024-06-19 22:08:16 INFO com.service.cd.CDLUpdateRungService 82 : LOCAL-1 : GrandParent : 
 GrandParent{ladderSequenceId=95a85ab3-fb83-46db-8a8b-530617a05560, ladderId='00276', ladderName='TestLadder', ladderAccountNumber='X04977780', ladderRungs=[
 Parent{ladderRungSequenceId=9b49bb00-a395-4d41-88b9-36df45623335, ladderId='00276', ladderRungNumber=3, rungPositions=[
 Child{ladderPositionId=9874a624-1cd5-49c6-9db0-e1479339f4f7, ladderRungNumber=3}]}, 
 Parent{ladderRungSequenceId=32fc34e3-5d84-4589-a9bd-f01da276b084, ladderId='00276', ladderRungNumber=1, rungPositions=[
 Child{ladderPositionId=92e5cc6e-ab63-48da-a0b0-d2a624919c56, ladderRungNumber=1}]}, 
 Parent{ladderRungSequenceId=f17b5f20-dd53-4469-b382-efabd3a2e0a1, ladderId='00276', ladderRungNumber=4, rungPositions=[
 Child{ladderPositionId=fc5bf7b6-7ca3-4c1a-8511-7806894deff6, ladderRungNumber=4}, 
 Child{ladderPositionId=a8303128-c24c-4d60-9a5b-90215db2bc88, ladderRungNumber=4}, 
 Child{ladderPositionId=693be613-ae00-4949-a253-fb720cb2f241, ladderRungNumber=4}]}, 
 Parent{ladderRungSequenceId=7482ee82-1e3d-41b1-81b3-82fa76e230f0, ladderId='00276', ladderRungNumber=2, rungPositions=[
 Child{ladderPositionId=f276b538-2ec7-4353-aa93-2ddc66dd1741, ladderRungNumber=2}, 
 Child{ladderPositionId=31e49ce5-abea-4bdf-bad0-8ae05a5594d3, ladderRungNumber=2}, 
 Child{ladderPositionId=1952e6ad-1e0c-4cb1-ba7b-31af88a075e2, ladderRungNumber=2}, 
 Child{ladderPositionId=53188e4b-bdcb-4189-88d8-eee7c748414f, ladderRungNumber=2}, 
 Child{ladderPositionId=6009dffc-5179-4174-9efb-a78726e8b78f, ladderRungNumber=2}]}]}
jakarta.persistence.PersistenceException: Converting `org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException` to JPA `PersistenceException` : detached entity passed to persist: com.model.entities.Child
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:165)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:175)
    at org.hibernate.internal.ExceptionConverterImpl.convert(ExceptionConverterImpl.java:182)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.firePersist(SessionImpl.java:743)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.persist(SessionImpl.java:721)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.orm.jpa.ExtendedEntityManagerCreator$ExtendedEntityManagerInvocationHandler.invoke(ExtendedEntityManagerCreator.java:360)
    at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy139.persist(Unknown Source)
    at com.fmr.fbt.fi.ladder.service.db.EntityManagerDBService.saveGrandParent(EntityManagerDBService.java:53)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)

Here I am trying to create new Child Entities and save to the database. Before saving to database i want to delete that first. So, called the remove method. I debug the code and found "remove" was never called but not throwing any exception even, it seems the call was ignored. And during saving it is giving the exception as mentioned. For new child entity i tried to use the "persist" method.
get Exception:
Converting org.hibernate.PersistentObjectException to JPA PersistenceException : detached entity passed to persist:
If I enable "merge" method, getting below exception:
java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: org.hibernate.ObjectDeletedException: deleted instance passed to merge: [com.model.entities.Child#]
Question

What's wrong i am doing here?
Why remove is not impacting the database?


Hi @SPL, can you try adding @NoArgsConstructor annotation to the class Child and check once?

you are invoking clone() method in Child class object. But the class didn't implement Cloneable interface. Did you share the right code here?

@VasanthSubramanian , I messed up while posting my code. In actual clone() was there. Also, i added NoArgsConstructor and AllArgsConstructor in Child class. Still it seems remove() has no effect. I posted the updated code.

Why are you using clone? That is your issue. Remove that and update the existing persistent instances.

The issue is that the entities you are trying to persist are detached. In that @Transactional method, there is only the reference to the aforementioned entities.
There are multiple ways to handle this.

either refactor the code in order to do operations on attached entities.
either try fetching rungPositions eagerly. Note that this might have performance penalties, depending on where else the repository calls are made.
either perform another query to get rungPositions based on GrandParent directly in the saveGrandParent method.

I would go with the last way.

i updated the code as per your second option but no effect. My first problem is child remove() is not making any effect to the DB. So, after child remove if I log the grand parent, i can still see old entities are there.

also, if i follow the last option, that will be a extra query to the DB, and as remove is not making any effect to DB, so that will retrieve old data again. In actual, that child table has constrains which will violate if i try to save the same cloned entities. First i need to see if remove is working and then i can try the last option which might work. Can you please help me why child remove() is not working?
